# Detecting rows that fail INET_ATON() in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to do a mysql select query like:

```
select INET_ATON(ip_address), id from table ...
```

Where INET_ATON fails because the IP in the column is invalid?

We found a bad entry in our table and now we want to make sure there aren't any more.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton I can see:

> INET_ATON() returns NULL if it does not understand its argument.

Therefore:

```
 select INET_ATON(ip_address) ip, id from table where ip IS NULL
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Have you tested this? You can't refer to an alias in a WHERE clause. You can fix it by putting the INET_ATON() call in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This worked: SELECT ip, id FROM routes WHERE INET_ATON(ip) IS NULL;

Answer (score 0):

As per docs:

> `INET_ATON()` returns `NULL` if it does not understand its argument.
>   […] `INET_ATON()` may or may not return a non-NULL result for
>   short-form IP addresses (such as '127.1' as a representation of
>   '127.0.0.1'). Because of this, `INET_ATON()` should not be used for
>   such addresses.

So you need to at least detect non-NULL columns that render NULL:

```
WHERE ip_address IS NOT NULL AND INET_ATON(ip_address) IS NULL
```

If you need to fine tune and tell out short-form IP addresses from plain invalid ones it gets trickier but I guess you don't really need that level of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT ip, id FROM routes WHERE INET_ATON(ip) IS NULL;
```